# "Run Custom Tool" has disappeared from context menu in VS2008 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings

After Right click on **.tt files ->

I can't see it from the properties window neither ...

I have CodeSmith 5.1 installed also ...

Answer (score 14):

Select the file and hit F4, what is shown next to 'Custom Tool'? If it's not 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator', set it to that. Mine is also set to Build Action: None and Output Directory: Do not copy

Comment: Txn for nswering, the problem is that i see only FileName and FullPath , there is no "Custom Tool" ...

Comment: I feel like an idiot ... Tools - Customize - ToolBars - ContextMenus - shows the context menu bar but when I click on Ok( next to Keyboard ) the toolbar disappears ... Should I simply reinstall VS2008

Comment: Still relevant in VS2022 apparently. This was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is a Website rather than a Web Application Project t4 won't work and you won't see 'Run Custom Tool' in the right click menu ..

Answer (score 2):

The exact explanation of the solution for this problem could be found [here](http://biasecurities.com/blog/2008/visual-studio-website-project-add-context-menu-for-t4-files/)